# WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable When it was working a minute before

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a scraper using Selenium, and it was working just fine until 15 minutes ago..
All of sudden, I get the following error every time I execute. This is my code:

```
searchDate = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/input[@placeholder='select sold date range']")))
searchDate.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

And the error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.163)
```

And my chrome setting:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory': new_dir}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/Program Files/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
```

I tried to solve the problem by chain the options as other post suggested, such as:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
prefs = {'download.default_directory': new_dir}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/Program Files/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
```

But I still get the exact same error. Why did it happen?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

++

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-c7d533e1df88> in <module>
----> 1 wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='daterangepicker_start']"))).click()
      2 
      3 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     69         while True:
     70             try:
---> 71                 value = method(self._driver)
     72                 if value:
     73                     return value

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py in __call__(self, driver)
    126     def __call__(self, driver):
    127         try:
--> 128             return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
    129         except StaleElementReferenceException:
    130             return False

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py in _find_element(driver, by)
    413         raise e
    414     except WebDriverException as e:
--> 415         raise e
    416 
    417 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py in _find_element(driver, by)
    409     if thrown."""
    410     try:
--> 411         return driver.find_element(*by)
    412     except NoSuchElementException as e:
    413         raise e

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
--> 978             'value': value})['value']
    979 
    980     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.92)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check if your chrome browser is compatible with your chrome browser? 
Could be possible your chrome is autommatically updated and now your chrome browser is not compatible with chrome driver.

[You can download chrome driver from here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Comment: Hi, I have the same error again, when try to use something like ```wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='daterangepicker_start']"))).click()```. Selenium works when I use ```browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"advanced-contents\"]")``` And my both chrome and chrome driver is up to date. What could be the problem? Thank you in advance...

Comment: again today chrome browser version is automatically updated to Version 81.0.4044.92. so you need to updatee your chromer driver from above link to ChromeDriver 81.XXX :)

Comment: but my chrome driver verison says "ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69"... and I think this is the latest one. No? I'm so confused... haha

Comment: let me know your browser version and chromedriver version

Comment: My browser is: Version 81.0.4044.92 (Official Build) (64-bit), and my chromedriver is:  81.0.4044.69, I added the error message if you need to look at it! Thank you for helping!

Comment: ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 try this I am using this its working for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211664/discussion-between-sarah-kim-and-dipak-bachhav).